# Webform dropdownlist Value and NAME

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, webforms, vb.net-2010

Hi hoping this is a simple question and im just doing something silly...
i have a aspx page and aspx.vb page for the code behind my webform 
the page has a asp dropdown list popualted from a SQL data source

```
ID= DDL23
DataTextField="displayname" 
DataValueField="ValueName"
```

in the vb file im using `writer.writeElementString(DDL23.SelectedValue)` inorder to get the value within the file being generated by my background code  which gives me the value exactaly how i want it

**how do i get the name is there something like**

```
DDL23.SelectedName
```

? am i missing something simple?

the html displayed on the page is below

```
<select name="DDL23" id="DDL23">
<option value="this is a value">this is the displayname</option>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
String selectedText = DDL23.SelectedItem.Text;
```

Should get you the name.

Comment: thank you very much, i knew it would be something simple. i just couldnt get it right.